# Why tick() doesn't work int this unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, rxjs

I have a directive which remembers scroll position for some div.

**directive**

```js
   constructor(
        private elementRef: ElementRef,
        private restoreValueService: KeyValueMapService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
      const debounceTimeValue = 200;
      console.log(this.elementRef.nativeElement);
      fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'scroll').pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroyed$),
        debounceTime(debounceTimeValue)
      ).subscribe((event: Event) => this.onScroll());
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.destroyed$.next(true);
      this.destroyed$.complete();
    }

    onScroll(): void {
      console.log('on Scroll');
      this.scrollValue = this.elementRef.nativeElement.scrollTop;
      this.restoreValueService.values.set('scroll', this.scrollValue);
    }
```

I also have small service with Map which should receive scroll value:

```js
export class KeyValueMapService {
    values: Map<string, any> = new Map();
}
```

I'm trying to test it using `fakeAsync()` and `tick()` but when I run this test, expectations run before callback method `onScroll()` and the test fails, because the map doesn't have a scroll value yet.

**spec**

```js
fdescribe('RestoreScrollDirective', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
    let component: TestComponent;
    let debugElement: DebugElement;
    let innerDiv: DebugElement;
    let keyValueService: KeyValueMapService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        keyValueService = new KeyValueMapService();

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ TestComponent, RestoreScrollDirective ],
            providers: [ {provide: KeyValueMapService, useValue: keyValueService}]
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
        innerDiv = debugElement.query(By.css('.outer-div'));
    });

    it('Should save in service its last scroll position',  fakeAsync(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();

        // I scroll div element which holds directive

        const scrollPosition = 250;
        const element = innerDiv.nativeElement as HTMLDivElement;
        element.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition);
        fixture.detectChanges();

        // I simulate time passage needed to my callback run, due to the debounce time

        tick(201);
        fixture.detectChanges();

        console.log('Exceptations begin'); // this logs earlier than 'on Scroll'
        const map = keyValueService.values;
        expect(map.has('scroll')).toBe(true);
        expect(map.get('scroll')).toBe(scrollPosition);
    }));
});
```

Anyone can explain to me why my expectations are executed before `onScroll()` method? 'Exceptations begin' is logged earlier than `on Scroll` even when I use `tick` with a higher value than debounce time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Angular doesn't trigger the event if we call scroll methods of the HTMLElement API. We need to trigger using other approach:

```js
innerDiv.dispatchEvent(new Event('scroll'));
// or 
innerDiv.triggerEventHandler('scroll', null);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately it didn't help, even with changing function to `async` and `await fixture.whenStable();` I still get the same behaviour - expectations run before `onScroll()` callback

Comment: pity (: I added one more change with a comment. Might be that div's is not rendered and no scroll there.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, still no success. Scrolling occurs becuase I can console log scrollTop from div and it shows 250 so my scrolling was performed

Comment: sorry for confusion, I updated the answer

Comment: Sorry for no feedback, I tried with manual trigger of event and it works! I used `dispatchEvent` because my event handler is registered through rxjs `fromEvent`. At the moment my handler is executed two times - first from manual trigger, then go exceptations and then second time handler. Still have no clue why this second is not affected by tick(), but first one is delayed as it should be so my test work :)